# Building specific branches on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfvc

I have a repository in VS Team Services which is setup as :

```
-root
 |
 | -Dev (.sln)
 |
 | -Releases
     |
     | - Test (.sln)
     | - Live (.sln)
```

Each build is working fine, however its pulling the entire repo and I just want it to pull a specific branch (Dev, Test or Live)

So I'm selecting the `Solution.sln` file in the dev branch...

[image: Screen shot of VSO]

Comment: With *VSO* you mean the *xxx.visualstudio.com* service? Just go to 'build definition->edit->repositories' and set 'default branch'??

Comment: I can't find that option

Comment: @stijn that would work for `Git`, but not for `TFVC`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the Repository tab you can specify your workspace mappings, the default mapping grabs your whole repository excluding the `$/project/drops` folder.

By changing the first mapping to not take `$/Project`, but `$/project/dev` you'll limit the scope of the get operation. If you no longer get the root of your team project, you can remove the cloak of the drop folder, that will only raise a warning otherwise:

[image]

The next thing you should do, if you're setting this build up to be a CI build, it to specify the folders that will trigger this build on the Tiggers tab, because, again by default, CI builds will trigger on any change in the whole team project.

[image]

To allow you to keep your build definition as a template, I suggest to use the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MySolution.sln` instead of `$/project/dev/Mysolution.sln`, that way you only need to update the mappings of a build definition after cloning it to another branch root or when saving it as a template.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. That really explains a lot.

Comment: I think I'm getting to a root cause though... my sln file is not being pulled to the build agent. I've looked the VSOwork folder and everything is there but the sln file....

"Cannot find path 'F:\vsowork\1\s\xxxxx.sln' because it does not exist."

I also tried your approach as above, which is correct.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Source Control Explorer to show which files are in the dev folder? And of the mapping of your build definition?